# How to update DetailView

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail, redraw

I have a swift app based on `Master-Detail` template. Every row in `MasterView` table is based on custom cell received from a nib. Every cell includes `UIlabel` and `UIbutton`. The logic of the app is following. If user taps on a row `DetailView` shows some details depending on selected row. The button on the row does not call `tableView(_, didSelectRowAtIndexPath)`. If user taps on the button inside a row only an image belongs to `DetailView` should be changed (other elements on `DetailView` remain the same) but it isn't. If I select another row and than select previous row back, changed image is shown on the `DetailView` as it was foreseen. The question is how to redraw the image in the `DetailView` just by tapping on the button.
I've tried to do following but with no success:

```
class MasterViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var detailViewController: DetailViewController?

   @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
       //method to set new image
       detailViewController!.setNewImage()
       detailViewController!.view.setNeedsDisplay()    
   }
}

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "itemCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MasterViewCell
        cell?.detailView = self.detailViewController
        return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I've used protocol-delegate mechanism. Now the code is:

```
//protocol declaration:
protocol MasterViewCellDelegate: class {
  func updateImage(sender: MasterViewCell, detVC: DetailViewController)
}
// cell class
class MasterViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var masterViewCellDelegate: MasterViewCellDelegate?  // protocol property
   weak var masterViewController: MasterViewController? {
     didSet {
        // set delegate
        self.masterViewDelegate = masterViewController!.detailViewController
     }
   }

   @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
     var detVC: DetailViewController?
     if let split = masterViewController!.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        detVC = (controllers[controllers.count - 1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
   }
   // call delegate 
   masterViewCellDelegate?.updateImage(self, detVC: detVC)
}

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "itemCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MasterViewCell
        cell?.masterViewController = self
        return cell!
}

// declare detailviewcontroller as delegate 
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, MasterViewCellDelegate {
  func updateImage(sender: MasterViewCell, detVC: DetailViewController){
    detVC.setNewImage()
  }
}
```

It may well be that this solution is excessively complex, but it works and easy could be adapted for various purposes.

Comment: While your method is correct, we often don't use delegations for master->detail communication. We use delegations when the detailView wants to **talk back** to the master.

Comment: @RayTso, I agree. But for this specific problem it seems the best solution.

Comment: You ***do*** know I'm talking about segues?

Comment: @RayTso, I thought we were talking about delegations. I start thinking that didn't get you point.

Comment: For ***master to detail*** communication: segues, for ***detail to master*** communications: delegations. But you don't *have to* do it this way, it's just normally done this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a handler

```
typealias ButtonHandler = (Cell) -> Void

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    var changeImage: ButtonHandler?

    func configureButton(changeImage: ButtonHandler?) {
        self.changeImage = changeImage
    }


    @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: UIButton) {
        changeImage?(self)
    }
}
```

And in your MasterView

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell

            cell.configureButton(setNewImage())

            return cell
        }

        private func setNewImage() -> ButtonHandler {
            return { [unowned self] cell in
                let row = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row //Get the row that was touched
                //set the new Image
            }
        }
```

SOURCE: [iOS Swift, Update UITableView custom cell label outside of tableview CellForRow using tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931731/ios-swift-update-uitableview-custom-cell-label-outside-of-tableview-cellforrow)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But actually I've found another solution, that seems more flexible and could be adapted for other purposes. See my comment below